# Giving feedback to supervisor on year performance

Tags: feedback

My boss recently asked me to give feedback on his performance during the year (with his manager on copy).

I am not good at giving feedback and wanted to get some thoughts...  This is the first year in which we work together and I wanted to point out that he has shown a strong-work ethic.

Is it appropriate to go like:

- You've shown a strong work ethic during the year

Not fully convinced about going like "You've", is there any other better way? Otherwise if his manager is CCd, is it better to speak about him in the 3rd person?

in addition, any other advise about giving feedback on year performance will be helpful

Answer (score 7):

When your boss/manager asks for your feedback about his performance I think that he is interested in how you judge his management of you and other members of your team.

So I think he (and perhaps his boss) are probably not that interested in whether you think he has a strong work-ethic.

In my opinion far more interesting/relevant points would be.

- Does he give clear instructions in what is expected of you?
- Does he regularly track your progress?
- Does he make enough time for you?
- How does he react when you disagree with him about something?
- Does he shield you from people from other teams who come to you with requests?

Comment: This is good advise, I wasn't thinking it from that point of view

Comment: Do you have more relevant points like these? Or any recommended place for looking similar points?

Comment: You could add: Do you get clear feedback? Are you given the right amount of time for tasks? How often do plans and priorities change unexpectedly? Do you feel valued? Do you have enough autonomy in your work? Would you recommend your team/company to a friend?

Answer (score 0):

When giving feedback it is always good to be specific so the person can understand a bit of context of your feedback:

> You've shown a strong work ethic during the year

Is vague and could mean 100 different things. To which in particular are you referring to? You can try adding a further explanation

> You've shown a strong work ethic during the year. When important customer X started bossing me around you stood up for me.

This is much more specific and clearly shows what do you value in your boss. In a similar way, should provide some feedback on the areas to improve his management style.